# Fetch external link of ecs task running from aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

How to fetch the external link of aws ecs task running which has the public ip of container instance and port of the task running?

I am managing task/service execution from cli and would like to fetch the external link which is shown in the aws UI from aws cli. I tried describe-tasks command of aws cli but it doesn't return the public IP address of the instance the task is running on.

Is there a way to fetch the same from aws cli?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to get the external link via cli or sdk? I am looking for the external link as well.

Comment: Hi @testphreak, i was able to achieve this with cli, instead of single cli command need to run multiple to fetch the external ip for service

Comment: Would be great if you could show a working example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is quite the pain in the neck, but it will do what you want:

1. List your tasks by service name

`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster mycluster --service-name my-service-name`

2. Get the details of a task using the task ARN from the above.

`aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster mycluster --tasks arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:999999999999:task/ad0ba3e9-ac3b-4a4c-a1af-de3e06f46dfa`

3. The task description includes two pieces of information you need: the network bindings, which includes the port (look for the one that is mapped to the service port you care about), and the container instance ARN. (NOT the container ARN. Don't make that mistake and be super-confused when the next step fails, like I did). Using the container instance's ARN, get the details of the container instance:

`aws ecs describe-container-instances --cluster mycluster --container-instances arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:999999999999:container-instance/707e5193-51e3-454b-ba09-9745c5d7f527`

4. As part of this description, you should be able to get the EC2 instance ID & query EC2 for more details:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-c91aee40d92c23b3c
    ^^^^ NOT ECS`

The output of this command should include the private IP of the EC2 instance. This IP + previously computed port should correspond to the external link from the web UI.

NOTE: Data has been anonymized, but should still LOOK like what you can expect to see. Also I omitted AWS region and profile params, which I have set to defaults using environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

This should show your Ingress IP address which is a public URL and is typically then mapped to your domain as a Type A record using AWS route53 console so your users can reach same just using your URL domain.com/lalala

```
aws ecs describe-services --service my-http-service
```

to discover this command and others generally the `aws` command line tool is actually very friendly ... just issue

```
aws help
```

then view that top level list of available subcommands then drill down by issuing

```
aws ecs help
```

and repeat above burrowing deeper into the available commands until you reach what could work ... as in

```
ecs ecs describe-services help
```

Comment: This is the best example of how to get started with `aws ec2` without guessing OP's usage.

Comment: Hi @Scott Stensland I have already checked that and the details returned in that are service details, deployments and events. In service details load balancer details are shown but I am not using any load balancer in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the answer you want by running:

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster foo --tasks 8591006e-6f05-4886-bc4a-58d9063d3852
```

This will contain the networkBindings section like this:

```
"networkBindings": [
                    {
                        "protocol": "tcp", 
                        "bindIP": "0.0.0.0", 
                        "containerPort": 7000, 
                        "hostPort": 32769
                    }, 
                    {
                        "protocol": "tcp", 
                        "bindIP": "0.0.0.0", 
                        "containerPort": 7001, 
                        "hostPort": 32768
                    }
                ]
```

Then you're golden!

Comment: Wrong answer. @pmann is asking for "external link of aws ecs task" and that information isn't present in the NetworkBindings section. I can only see it from the UI console.

Comment: It is present actually. You just need to add the IP and port together to construct the external link together.

Comment: Would be great if you could show an example of how you are getting the IP. Because when I tried it, all I got was the networkBindings section without an IP. bindIP isn't external ip if that's what you mean.

Comment: Precisely! All the answers I've found overlook the fact that the network bindings don't contain the external IP... which is exactly what I (and presumably, the OP) need!